# Web API HttpClient returning "Unauthorized" Status Code

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I have a strange behavior with my usage of `HttpClient` in a WinForms application (trying to connect to a Web API hosted by an Azure Website).

In simple terms:

1. My clients are sometimes able to connect, and sometimes not.
2. When they cannot, if I go to a browser and load the url (`http://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/entity`), then go back to the client and try to connect, it works fine.
3. The problem I'm having happens on a corporate network (not sure if this is related but I thought I'd mention it).

What could cause the connection to become `authorized` only after I try to connect via a browser first?

Edit:

Here's my code:

```
    public static User GetUser()
    {
        HttpClient client = StaticFunctions.GetHttpClient();
        string parameters = "username=username&password=password"
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/user?" + parameters).Result; 
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var user = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<User>().Result;
            return user;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        NetworkCredential credentials = null;
        if (GlobalVariables.CurrentUser != null)
        {
            credentials = new NetworkCredential(GlobalVariables.CurrentUser.UserName, GlobalVariables.CurrentUser.Password);
        }
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();

        handler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        handler.Credentials = credentials;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(PublicClasses.GlobalVariables.BaseUriString);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        return client;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: I have had a similar issue before where I was required to open a Browser Before certain applications can work. I will go out on a limb and say please check your connection settings and see if it is set to dial a connection. That being said.. It is a vague guess as you show no code:-)

Comment: Unfortunately, not with my code at the moment (will be tonight) but in the meantime, what do you mean by "see if it is set to dial a connection"?

Comment: Is there some sort of client certificate that your infrastructure needs?

Comment: @PeterRitchie, I don't know exactly, but one thing I've noticed from time to time is that the URL in the HttpClient sometimes get modified by pre-pending it with some letters/numbers that I don't understand...I'm wondering if this is related to a client certificate requirement (which I have zero understanding of) some proxying by the infrastructure I don't understand or something like that...I'd like to detect the problem before going to my IT department, which is overwhelmed with more important projects.

Comment: What happens when you can't connect? If you get an exception or error response, inspect those. How often does `GetUser()` get called, enough to trigger some connection (pooling) limit anywhere, although each instance uses its own connection pool? So try disposing it or using a single instance. Do you also have to restart the application after visiting the URI with a web browser to make it working again?

Comment: @CodeCaster, the GetUser() method is not called frequently, but the GetHttpClient method is called every time a user has to hit the Web API (unrelated question of whether this is efficient).  The troubling thing is that its not repeatable and the weird thing is how the connection works after going to the URL via the browser.  The message returned Status Code is just "Unauthorized".